# How do I simplify these For-loops to save lines of code?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, simplify

The output of the code displays the following:

[image]

The code below seems pretty funky to me, even as a newbie. I imagine the code can be done more efficiently or at least lines of code can be saved without having to whip out so many loops.

If anyone can provide a cleaner solution, thanks in advance.

```
public class diamond    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int c=1; c<=10; c++) {
            for (int d=1; d<=11-c; d++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int e=2; e<c*2; e++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int i=1; i<=11-c; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int f=2; f<=10; f++) {
            for (int g=1; g<=f; g++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int h=2; h<22-f*2; h++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j=1; j<=f; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that I understood what your code is doing right away is the biggest indication that it is very good the way it is.  In professional development, clear, readable code is far more valuable than shortening it by a few lines or micro-optimizing it to save a few CPU cycles.

Comment: @VGR I can't agree that this is "clear, readable code". Perhaps you found that because you already knew very precisely what it was trying to achieve. I don't think most people who knew absolutely nothing about the problem being addressed would understand what that code was doing "right away" just by reading it. Even after knowing the problem being solved, most of the answers published below are easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to notice repetitive patterns in your code and factor it out.

You could use a helper method to print a series of N characters:

```
public static void printNTimes(char value, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(value);
    }
}
```

You can generalize the approach by using constants for the characters involved and the size of the diamond.

```
private static final char OuterChar = '*';
private static final char InnerChar = ' ';
private static final int Size = 10;
```

And add another helper method to print a row with N instances of one character on the outside, and `2 * (Size - N)` characters on the inside:

```
private static void printRow(int n) {
    printNTimes(OuterChar, n);
    printNTimes(InnerChar, (Size - n) * 2);
    printNTimes(OuterChar, n);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
public class diamond
{
    private static final char OuterChar = '*';
    private static final char InnerChar = ' ';
    private static final int Size = 10;

    public static void printNTimes(char value, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(value);
        }
    }

    private static void printRow(int n) {
        printNTimes(OuterChar, n);
        printNTimes(InnerChar, (Size - n) * 2);
        printNTimes(OuterChar, n);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int c = Size; c >= 1; c--) {
            printRow(c);
        }
        for (int c = 2; c <= Size; c++) {
            printRow(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for OOP design. I'd change from using hard-coded strings in the method calls, though.

Comment: @CreationEdge I don't think I was using OOP design in my original answer, but thanks for the compliment. :) I've modified my answer to take your suggestion into account and refactor a bit more.

Comment: Given that this is a Java question, your "const" declarations won't compile. I assume you meant "static" instead, right?

Comment: @skomi Looks like I meant `static final`. It has been a while since I used Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
int max=9,min=10;
        for(int i=0;i<19;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++){

                if(j<min || j>max){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            if(i<9){
                min--;
                max++;
            }
            else {
                min++;
                max--;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this rather clear but YMMV.

```
for( int i = 10; i >= 1; i-- ){
    String s = "**********".substring(0, i);
    System.out.printf( "%-10s%10s\n", s, s );
}
for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){
    String s = "**********".substring(0, i);
    System.out.printf( "%-10s%10s\n", s, s );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is repeated within the loop:

```
  for (int d=1; d<=11-c; d++)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }
```

you could write it to a variable and print it out twice. That would eliminate two loops. (one subloop in each outer loop)

Answer (score 0):

I like to wrap logic in code that is easy to read and maintain so instead of doing loads of nested for-loops I wrote a class with descriptive methods.

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow.diamond;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Diamond {
    final List<String> rows;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Diamond(10));
    }

    public Diamond(int width) {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int stars = 1; stars <= width; stars++) {
            // add all rows, start from the middle and build around it
            addRows(stars, width);
        }
    }

    private void addRows(int stars, int width) {
        String row = generateRow(stars, width);
        // add on top
        this.rows.add(0, row);
        if (stars > 1) {
            // add to bottom
            this.rows.add(row);
        }
    }

    private String generateRow(int stars, int width) {
        String row = "";
        int spaces = width - stars;
        for (int j = 0; j < stars; j++) {
            row += "*";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++) {
            row += "  ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < stars; j++) {
            row += "*";
        }
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String diamond = "";
        for (String row : rows) {
            diamond += row + System.lineSeparator();
        }
        return diamond;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an fun question as you get to see how everybody takes a different approach to solving it. This way just gives you a string that is "padded" with another character on the other side.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++) {
        System.out.println(printPadded(11 - c, '*',  (c - 1) * 2, ' '));
    }
    for (int f = 10; f >= 2; f--) {
        System.out.println(printPadded(11 - f, '*',  (f - 1) * 2, ' '));
    }
}

public static String printPadded(int padCount, char padCharacter, 
          int middleCount, char middleCharacter) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(padCount * 2 + middleCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < padCount; i++) {
        s.append(padCharacter);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < middleCount; i++) {
        s.append(middleCharacter);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < padCount; i++) {
        s.append(padCharacter);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```